# how to add a csrf token to a fake symfony form

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a form called `ObjectCollectionOuterForm` which extends from `sfForm`. `ObjectCollectionOuterForm` is the main form of an embedded form, each embedded form has disabled its csrf with: `$this->disableLocalCSRFProtection()`, so now my form protection depends on the outer form but since it´s not a `sfFormDoctrine` dependent it has a field called `_csrf_token` but with no value inside. How can I generate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSRF protection is handled by `sfForm` class, it has nothing to do with `sfFormDoctrine`. The secret should get generated for you, but if you have problems you can pass it as a third argument to your form's constructor:

```
$form = new ObjectCollectionOuterForm($defaults, $options, $CSRFSecret);
```

Comment: Sorry for my late acceptance, I was kind of giving up on this until I saw your answer, it did worked :), thanks a lot.